# how to submit a text field input from a user in a views filter form to a javascript ?

Tags: views, javascript, forms

I am trying to fetch the user entered text value precisely a zip code which will be taken as input in the views exposed filter form and this value should be sent to the Java script function and I have this java script function which calculates the required LAT LON based on the zipcode and gives back the result.
The problem is I can use the drupal_add_js function to add the js file and also pass the value of zip code (I think so I am not sure though) I am wondering if I can send the zipcode value entered by the user only on form submit to the js file i.e can I send the value of zipcode to the js file only when the user submits the views exposed filter form by pressing the apply button?

I know that we can add a js file and send the values using drupal_add_js function but just not sure if this can be synced with the form submission button ?
 how can this be done?  please help me in this, any pointers in this regard are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

got it I never used Jquery before and jquery is magic it when used with drupal behaviours as magic just listens to click or any event you want it to listen to and passes the value and you can retrieve it using $(# id of the field).val()[.val() is a function to retrieve the value].